Google Chrome Processes Persist After Disposing WebDriver in Selenium During dotnet test
I'm encountering an issue where Google Chrome processes persist in the task manager even after I dispose of the WebDriver instance in my Selenium-based automation tests. Below is a minimal example that demonstrates this problem:
IExample Interface
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.V85.Page;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace ExampleNamespace
{
    public interface IExample : IDisposable
    {
        Task Login();
        void Logout();
    }
    public class ExampleBaseClass : IExample
    {
        private readonly IWebDriver _driver;
        private bool _disposed = false;

        public ExampleBaseClass()
        {
            var options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--headless");
            options.AddArgument("--no-sandbox");
            options.AddArgument("--disable-dev-shm-usage");

            _driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        }

        public async Task Login()
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/login");
            await Task.Delay(2000); // Simulate login process
        }

        public void Logout()
        {
            _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/logout");
        }

        // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Dispose managed resources.
                        _driver.Quit();
                        _driver.Dispose();
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }
        }

        // Finalizer
        ~ExampleBaseClass()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}

ExampleProcesses Class
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ExampleNamespace
{
    public class ExampleProcesses : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IExample _exampleBase;

        public ExampleProcesses(IExample exampleBase)
        {
            _exampleBase = exampleBase ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(exampleBase));
        }

        public async Task UpdateExample()
        {
            try
            {
                await _exampleBase.Login();
                // Simulate some operations
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                _exampleBase.Logout();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                _exampleBase.Close();
                _exampleBase.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}

Run
[Fact]
public async Task ExampleRun()
{
    await _exampleProcess.UpdateExample();
}

Problem:
Despite calling _driver.Quit() and _driver.Dispose(), Chrome processes remain in the task manager when running tests using dotnet test. This causes resource leakage and potential conflicts with other tests.

you don't need to dispose.  What you are disposing is just a reference to the executable.  Just use driver.quit().  If that doesn't close the browser/driver after a period of time, then it's likely the driver's session/handle was lost.  (Chromedriver is a bit buggy)  Try/catching the previous calls can sometimes give you more details... usually it's something like "session was closed/has expired...etc...".  Basically driver has lost connection to the browser's wire protocol.

@browsermator I do have a flag _disposed to check. should I move _driver.Quit() higher up, perhaps inside public void Dispose()

I'd get rid of all the dispose logic, especially the GC.SuppressFinalize.   Your driver reference isn't "heavy" enough to have to deal with manually.  All the heavy stuff is inside the driver executable (the server) and that's separate from your code.

I see, it works with the quit. I may have misunderstood what dispose does in this case. thanks @browsermator
